# What's the point of adding NOT NULL to primary key field in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, constraints, primary-key, notnull

What's the point of adding `NOT NULL` to a *primary key* field? Primary key is already *not null* + *unique*.

Here is an example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE student (
  id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  name varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

Why not to define it like this instead:

```sql
CREATE TABLE student (
  id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They are the same. Primary key got `NOT NULL` *automatically*.

Comment: soo why peaple add NOT NULL??

Comment: @Yosef this is just a matter of style. And `mysqldump` add this `NOT NULL` when dump a table, because of a bug for allowing NULL in mysql.

Answer (score 5):

You are asking, why do people bother adding the NOT NULL when it is unnecessary? Just because it is good style, I guess. And makes it explicit to the reader.

Answer (score 4):

`NULL` is not equivalent to `NULL`(as `NULL` indicates an unknown or absent value), so you will be permitted to have multiple records that have `NULL` for the id, even though there's a primary key / unique constraint defined, hence the use of `NOT NULL`. That's if MySql even allows you to define a primary key on a nullable field.

In addition, as a primary key is often used in a foreign key in other tables, having one or more `NULL` values wouldn't make sense.

Comment: `NULL` on `PRIMARY KEY` violate ISO standard and considered as a bug in mysql: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=390 . See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key for the justification of NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

If `PRIMARY KEY` is declared without `NOT NULL`, `NOT NULL` is added to `PRIMARY KEY` implicitly so `PRIMARY KEY` with or without `NOT NULL` is the same.

[**The MySQL documentation**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html) says as shown below:

> A unique index where all key columns must be defined as NOT NULL. If
> they are not explicitly declared as NOT NULL, MySQL declares them so
> implicitly (and silently). A table can have only one PRIMARY KEY. The
> name of a PRIMARY KEY is always PRIMARY, which thus cannot be used as
> the name for any other kind of index.

And also, [**the MySQL documentation**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/primary-key-optimization.html) says as shown below:

> The primary key for a table represents the column or set of columns
> that you use in your most vital queries. It has an associated index,
> for fast query performance. Query performance benefits from the NOT
> NULL optimization, because it cannot include any NULL values. ...